# Edge arrows are exceeding nodes borders. How to fix this?

Tags: graph, networkx, graphviz

I'm creating a graph in networkx and then I display it with graphviz.

I bold some edges using "penwidth" attribute, which makes them bolder the way I want it.

However this way the arrows of the edges are getting past the nodes borders as shown in this photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZ0Jh.jpg.

The problem might be equivalent to bolding the edges (increasing the width) without increase their size.

I'm using **dot version 2.43.0 (0)**

Here's the input:

```
digraph {
 rankdir=LR
 node [shape=plaintext]
 subgraph cluster_01 { 
  label = "Legend";
  key [label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
   <tr><td align="right" port="i1">item 1</td></tr>
   <tr><td align="right" port="i2">item 2</td></tr>
   <tr><td align="right" port="i3">item 3</td></tr>
   <tr><td align="right" port="i4">item 4</td></tr>
   </table>>]
  key2 [label=<<table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" cellborder="0">
   <tr><td port="i1">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td port="i2">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td port="i3">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   <tr><td port="i4">&nbsp;</td></tr>
   </table>>]
 key:i1:e -> key2:i1:w [style=dashed]
 key:i2:e -> key2:i2:w [color=gray]
 key:i3:e -> key2:i3:w [color=peachpuff3]
 key:i4:e -> key2:i4:w [color=turquoise4, penwidth=6]
 }
}
```

Here's the output:
[image: Graphviz output]

Here the turquoise edge is not just bolded but bigger than the other edges as well. Do you have any idea how to bold edges without increasing their size?

Comment: 1. Would you attach your input  2.indicate what output format 3. what version of dot (dot -V)?

Comment: would changing the arrowsize be acceptable (there will still be an offset on the where the arrow end)

Comment: try add arrowsize=.4 as edge attribute